# JAWS reads labels of parent tags before reading first element

Tags: html, angular, accessibility, jaws-screen-reader

I am trying to fix an accessibility defect in an Angular project at work. When a page loads and I start to tab through the page, the first element that is visible in the form is read twice. My code is something like below

```html
<form [formGroup]="form" role="form" attr.aria-label="Edit Form" novalidate>
   <div class="form-row">
       <div class="col-md-9 col-sm-12 col-lg-9 paddingLR0">
          <!-- Hidden code not rendered due to ngIf=false -->
          <div role="region" attr.aria-label="Edit button region" *ngIf="viewMode">
                <!-- Hidden elements not rendered due to ngIf=false -->
                <button *ngIf="isEditable" [disabled]="!canEdit" type="submit" (click)="enableEdit()">
                    Edit
                </button>
                <div class="back-header">
                    <a tabindex=0 (keyup.enter)="back()" (click)="back()" (mouseover)="changeBackIconOnHover('back-region-top')" (mouseout)="changeBackIcon('back-region-top')" id="back-region-top">
                        <img src="{{pathImg}}/back_black.png" 
                        <span class="margin-left10">Back</span>
                    </a>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
    <!-- More code here -->
</form>
```

If you see the code the first element that is visible is the `Edit` button, nested in a  div with role as region, which is in turn inside a form with role form. When I tab through the page instead of just reading the button just once **`Edit button`** JAWS reads **`Edit Form form region. Edit Button`** on first tab, then reads **`Edit button region. Edit Button`**. There are no tabindexes on the parent elements. Removing the role attribute and the corresponding labels does not work. How do I only make jaws read the edit button once?

Comment: Could you post a link to an example page reproducing the issue ?
It would also probably be useful to find out what is the actual HTML generated and seen by Jaws. Is this doable ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The above problem was occuring because of an empty div which had a tabindex=0.
So in the code snippet above I had a commented line

```html
<!-- Hidden code not rendered due to ngIf=false -->
```

That referred to multiple divs which are warning, success and error messages related to the form in my actual code. Each of those divs have an `ngIf` for conditional rendering and a tabindex=0 to make it tab accessible. Except one of those divs simply had a tabindex but no ngIf. So it was always rendered. Like below.

```html
<div tabindex=0>
   <div ngIf="condition"> {{errormessage}}
   </div>
</div>
```

If JAWS tabs onto an empty element it reads the previous labels. I removed the outer div which was remaining empty and the problem is solved.